# Blender export for photoshop mockups

Tags: export, file-format, .exr, template

**Context** : I have a product model that I made on blender 3.5.1 of a glass jar.

**Objective** : Create a .PSD template with an editable label and jar cap color for other users who don't know blender 3D modeling.

**Issues** : I tried to export .exr multilayer file to achieve that but the result was overly bright, noisy, and didn't help me out.

I wanted to export the specular / highlights of my model but I didn't know how to do that either.

**Question rephrased** : What format do I need to export my model from blender to photoshop? Is the specular an appropriate way to do that ? how to export the highlights seperatly from the model?